# PHP - Create File on Remote FTP and fputs() to it

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I have some data I'mm pulling from a MySQL DB using PHP, writing it to a file on a local server using `fputs()`, and uploading that file to a remote server using `ftp_put()`.  I'm concerned that when the data set gets larger, the `ftp_put()` will get issued before the file is finished being populated by `fputs()`

I thought it may be wise to first create the file on the remote server using `ftp_put()`, and then `fputs()` the data to that remote file from from a PHP variable populated with the necessary DB records.

Is this possible, and if so, how would it be accomplished?

Comment: Could you explain why you feel that fputs() will not run synchronously and wait on completion?  You could always fflush to be sure.

Comment: Hm, so you're saying, in this scenario, ftp_put() wouldn't run until fputs() had completed?